# How to show apps by default when "Use Start Fullscreen" is turned on instead of Pinned tiles?

Tags: windows-10

[image: setting]

In Windows, I turned the above start setting on.

[image: And it looks like this]

And the app list is shown by default.

But when I turn on the "Use Start full screen" option, it goes back to normal and it shows the "Pinned Tiles" by default. So how can I show the apps by default when turning on this option?

Windows 10 21H2

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be any way in Windows 10 to get the full screen
Start Menu to default to the All Apps view - it is only by clicking the
button on the Start Menu that's indicated below that you can access that
view in the full screen Start Menu:

[image]

You may remove the pinned apps from the Start menu, but that will just leave
a blank space in their place.

Perhaps the best solution is to replace the Windows Start menu with a
third-party product.

You could use the free and open-source
[Open-Shell](https://github.com/Open-Shell/Open-Shell-Menu),
which in addition expands the Windows Start menu with a very large choice
of options.

There exist other
[alternative third-party products](https://alternativeto.net/software/classic-start/)
that you could try.